# Change Colour of div inside asp repeater on itemdatabound

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to change the colour of a div inside a repeater on the itemdatabound event.
I have tried using a panel inside the itemdatabound like so;

```
protected void rptLocations_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
```

then inside

```
Panel cblock = e.Item.FindControl("pnlColour") as Panel;
cblock.Style.Add("background", rndColour);
```

but this throws an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'd rather use a div that a panel anyway.

**Is there any way to change the colour of a div from the itemdatabound event?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you checking for an `Item` and a `RepeatingItem` in the `ItemDataBound` event? Additionally it might be worth checking if `cblock` is null before you add a class to it, so that your application doesn't crash!

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified I'll fix that.

Comment: You might want to change the tag from asp-classic to asp.net too, to get a better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using HTMLCONTROLS

I use HtmlGenericControl to set the style attribute.

```
((HtmlGenericControl)(e.Item.FindControl("divColour"))).Attributes["style"] += ("background:" + rndColour + ";)");
```

Simple and effective!

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. One, there are a couple ways to add background color to a `div` or `Panel`.

```
pnlColour.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
pnlColour.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
```

Two, your `cblock` variable is most likely null. Make sure in your `ItemDataBound` that you are only searching for `cblock` when you want to by checking the type of the `RepeaterItem`. This example checks that the `RepeaterItem` is not in the `HeaderTemplate` or the `FooterTemplate`, but in the `ItemTemplate` or `AlternatingItemTemplate`.

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    Panel cblock = e.Item.FindControl("pnlColour") as Panel;
}
```